# Faster alternative than Symbolbrush for creating 2d colored surface plot using PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a realtime colored 2d surface graph using PyQtGraph and have found that drawing the symbols is too slow but I am not sure how to create the plot in another way that looks similar.  I am plotting x and y data and am using z (depth) data to color the symbols. Speed is of utmost importance for this application.

Running

`self.c_scan_graph.plot(x_list, y_list, symbol="s", symbolBrush=[self.colormap.map(c) for c in z], symbolSize=10,symbolPen=(255, 255, 255, 0))`

where `c_scan_graph` is a `PlotWidget` takes approximately 0.0096 seconds and outputs a plot like this over time:
[image]

If I run `self.c_scan_graph.plot(x_list, y_list)` it only takes 0.001 seconds. But it does not create a colored surface plot like I need.

Any suggestions on how I can speed this up and obtain a similar result?

Note: I was not able to create a colored pen in a similar fashion to the way I made the brush.

Comment: Considering that most computers cannot refresh more than 60-100 times per second, and that the human eye doesn't perceive any relative difference below 30-40ms, having a delay that takes less than 10ms doesn't seem a real problem, but this obviously depends on how often the plot changes. What is the frequency of the update? And does `z` change at the same frequency? Does the extent of the plot change over time? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: The plot isn't critical to have that high refresh rate but I think this plotting function is actually slowing down everything in the script.  Although I could be wrong here.  

This plotting is the slowest part of the script.  I have another function that grabs data from a laser data acquisition unit and everything else needs to be as streamlined as possible to be able to grab values from that unit at the highest rate (>1kHz).  When the data grabber function on a 1ms timer runs faster than it can plot I think it starts to lag out the entire script.

Comment: TLDR: The frequency of the update is every 32ms but with my other plotting functions and this it is over 32ms to plot everything but this plot takes the longest to plot by far.

Comment: Consider that, while the Graphics View framework is very well optimized and pyqtgraph also uses some "tricks" to accelerate drawing, we're still talking about a binding that necessarily passes through python, which is a *huge* bottleneck if you want to achieve near-realtime performance. It's very unlikely that you'll succeed in having a refresh that is constantly aligned with a 1kHz data rate and, as said above, it wouldn't change a lot: even the fastest graphics cards nowadays can't go faster than 200-250Hz, and our eyes can't keep up more than 40-50Hz.

Comment: The actual problem is how can you *actually* keep up the visual result without losing data? Since we know that you can't get an actual and reliable update with 1kHz, there's little point in trying to achieve it, but then the issue becomes in *what* the data should display and *how* the data changes during time: if there is not a lot of variations, then you can just use a low interval timer (around 10-15ms) and show the latest available sample, but if variation range is bigger, you may risk "aliasing" and you might consider some average computation (10-15 samples, then plot the average).

Comment: That said, there could be some level of optimization anyway, but it all depends on how you implemented it (and how do the `z` values change). If you can provide a proper [mre], we could take a look at that and see if there's room left for improvement.